# How to make DateFormat to parse String date to the assigned timezone

Tags: java, calendar, timezone, date-format, simpledateformat

I have a string date "20160104" of "yyyyMMdd" and it is of GMT-12 timezone.

Have been trying to parse the same to a Date object in Java. The expected result is

> FastTime = 1451908800000.  Monday, January 4, 2016 12:00:00 PM GMT

Tried something like this

```
DateFormat gmtMinus12 = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd");
gmtMinus12.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("Etc/GMT-12"));
// gmtMinus12.getCalendar().setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("Etc/GMT-12"));
gmtMinus12
    .setCalendar(Calendar.getInstance(TimeZone.getTimeZone("Etc/GMT-12")));

try {
  Date date = gmtMinus12.parse("20160104");

} catch (ParseException e) {
  // TODO Auto-generated catch block
  e.printStackTrace();
}
```

But the parsed output is

> FastTime = 1451822400000 . Sunday, January 3, 2016 12:00:00 PM GMT

How do I make the DateFormat to assume the same timezone with which it is assigned.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: add the time zone explicitly to the input string (and the parsing pattern)

Comment: Why would you expect the result to be midnight UTC when you're specifying a date in a different time zone? Basically, Monday January 4th 2016 in Etc/GMT-12 starts at the value you're already retrieving.

Comment: Sorry, I just edited my expected result.
20160104 00:00 at GMT-12. (assume Hawaii) could be 20160104 12:00 PM at London so I would expect the result would be Monday, January 4, 2016 12:00:00 PM GMT

Comment: Looks like DateFormat is doing -12 rather than doing +12 hrs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your real problem is not just using an old and awkward API but **using the wrong offset**. Please use

`Etc/GMT+12` (=UTC-12:00) instead of `Etc/GMT-12` (=UTC+12:00).

The outdated Etc/...-notation is very confusing because it uses the opposite sign of standard timezone offsets, see also the embbedded [translation table in TZ-database](https://github.com/eggert/tz/blob/master/etcetera).

Comment: Thank you so much. This has actually solved my problem.

Comment: Instead of writing "Etc/GMT+12", you could also write "GMT-12" (for sake of better readability).

Answer (score 1):

## java.time

You are using troublesome old date-time classes now supplanted by the java.time classes.

The [`LocalDate`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html) class represents a date-only value, without time-of-day and without time zone.

```
DateTimeFormatter f = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern ( "uuuuMMdd" );
LocalDate ld = LocalDate.parse ( "20160104" , f );
```

Now assign a time-of-day and an [offset-from-UTC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTC_offset) to deliver a [`OffsetDateTime`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/OffsetDateTime.html) object.

```
ZoneOffset offset = ZoneOffset.ofHours ( -12 );
LocalTime lt = LocalTime.MIN;  // 00:00
OffsetTime ot = OffsetTime.of ( lt , offset );
OffsetDateTime odt = ot.atDate ( ld );
```

> odt.toString(): 2016-01-04T00:00-12:00

To see that same moment in [UTC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordinated_Universal_Time), extract an `Instant`.

```
Instant instant = odt.toInstant();
```

> instant.toString(): 2016-01-04T12:00:00Z

As you expected, the time-of-day is noon on the 4th in UTC.

## Time zone

You should know that `GMT-12` is *not* a time zone. It is an [offset-from-UTC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTC_offset).

A [time zone](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_zone) is an offset *plus* a set of rules for handling anomalies such as Daylight Saving Time (DST).

If you know the intended time zone, you should apply it rather than a mere offset. Specify a [proper time zone name](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_zones_by_name) in the format of `continent/region`. Never use the 3-4 letter abbreviation such as `EST` or `IST` as they are not true time zones, not standardized, and not even unique(!).

```
ZoneId z = ZoneId.of( "Asia/Kamchatka" );
ZonedDateTime zdt = odt.atZoneSameInstant( z );
```

> zdt.toString(): 2016-01-05T00:00+12:00[Asia/Kamchatka]

## About java.time

The [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system) date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`.Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), & [`java.text.SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

The [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to java.time.

To learn more, see the [Oracle Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations. Specification is [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

Where to obtain the java.time classes?

- [**Java SE 8**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8) and [**SE 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9) and later

  - Built-in.
  - Part of the standard Java API with a bundled implementation.
  - Java 9 adds some minor features and fixes.
- [**Java SE 6**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_6) and [**SE 7**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_7)

  - Much of the java.time functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).
- [**Android**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system))

  - The [*ThreeTenABP*](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project adapts ***ThreeTen-Backport*** (mentioned above) for Android specifically.
  - See [*How to use…*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

The [ThreeTen-Extra](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) project extends java.time with additional classes. This project is a proving ground for possible future additions to java.time. You may find some useful classes here such as [`Interval`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/Interval.html), [`YearWeek`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearWeek.html), [`YearQuarter`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearQuarter.html), and [more](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/index.html).